# Retrieve "API Permissions" of Azure AD Application via PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

For reporting and monitoring purpose do I like to retrieve the information shown in the Azure portal for an application (App Registration) for "API permissions".

I have tried the following code

```
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId 'aa7e174d-2639-4ac7-9b11-6799466c3c9b'
$app.Oauth2Permissions
```

But this yields only the following information:

```
AdminConsentDescription : Allow the application to access foobar_HVV on behalf of the signed-in user.
AdminConsentDisplayName : Access foobar_HVV
Id                      : h1285f9d5-b00d-4bdb-979d-c4d6487fa000
IsEnabled               : True
Type                    : User
UserConsentDescription  : Allow the application to access foobar_HVV on your behalf.
UserConsentDisplayName  : Access foobar_HVV
Value                   : user_impersonation
```

But "API Permissions" for the application "foobar_HVV" shows totally different permissions. Especially the "Typ" (Delegate, Application) and the "Status" per permission are needed for my report.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to get the `API permissions`, you need to use the command below.

```
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId '<object-id of the App Registration>'
$app.requiredResourceAccess | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

[image]

The `ResourceAppId` is the `Application ID` of the service principal of the API e.g. `Microsoft Graph`, the `ResourceAccess` includes the permissions you added to the app, the `Scope` means the `Delegated permission`, `Role` means the `Application permission`.

My API permissions:

[image]

To check the details of the API permissions , you need to use the command below. For example, we want to know the details of the permission whose `Id` is `5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b` in the screenshot, its `Type` is `Role`, so we need to use `$sp.AppRoles`.

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'}
$sp.AppRoles | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq '5b567255-7703-4780-807c-7be8301ae99b'}
```

[image]

If you want to get the `Delegated permission`(`Type` is `Scope`), we need to use:

```
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'}
$sp.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 'e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d'}
```

[image]

To check `Status`, there is no direct way, you need to check the permissions granted by the admin of the service principal corresponds to the AD App in your AAD tenant.

First, get the service principal  `$appsp`:

```
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId '<object-id of the App Registration>'
$appsp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq $app.AppId}
```

Get the `Delegated permissions` which has been granted(`Status` is `Granted`):

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalOAuth2PermissionGrant -ObjectId $appsp.ObjectId -All $true | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

The `ResourceId` is the `Object Id` of the service principal of the API:

[image]

Get the `Application permissions` which has been granted(`Status` is `Granted`):

```
Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignedTo -ObjectId $appsp.ObjectId | ConvertTo-Json
```

The `Id` is the `Id` in the `ResourceAccess` in the first screenshot.

[image]

If the permission has not been granted(`Status` is `Not Granted`), you will not get the permission with the command above.

For example, I add a new `Application permission` in the portal, then run the command again, we can still get the permission which has been granted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have shown the PowerShell way of getting permission for the app. Does Microsoft provide the same information over graph api?

Comment: @RakeshGoswami yes It is possible to fetch permissions using Microsoft graph APIs. 
Perform the below steps to fetch the application permissions using graph APIs. 
1. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{applicationId} - In the response, you will get the requiredResourceAccess.resourceAppId. Once you get this resourceAppId, call second api i.e. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=appId eq '{resourceAppId}' then in the response you will get the appRoles. Now You can get the permission using  resourceId from the appRoles array.

Answer (score 0):

Looking after a new Solution using the 7.1 PowerShell and Az Client I've wrote follwing Script to solve this Issue:

```
# loop in all Applications then every Application Loop this one to 
$sp = $sp = az ad app list --display-name "yourapplication"
$spIdList = ($sp |ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable).requiredResourceAccess.resourceAccess
# retreive the ID from Bucket
$RoleAppID = ($sp| ConvertFrom-Json ).requiredResourceAccess.resourceAppId
## receive all Roles and lookup inside
$appRolesArray = (az ad sp show --id $RoleAppID | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable ).appRoles
 
$listRoles = @()
foreach ($itemSpId in $spIdList) {
    $itemSpId.id
     
    foreach($item in $appRolesArray ) {
        if ( $item.id -eq $itemSpId.id ){
            $listRoles += $item
            $item
        }
    }
}
$listRoles.count
```

## now you can do whatever you want with the List of those objects.

The Goal was to use the "az client"

Comment: If anybody has achieved to retrieve the List with "jmespath" using --query for the client, then please let me know, that can be easier then :)