# How to export delegated permissions and application permissions for azure app registrations using graph api

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a script to export into a csv both `delegated permissions` and `application permissions` for all of my azure app registrations using `graph api` requests.

In my script,

step 1, i'm exporting all available app registrations, then create a custom ps object named `$Data`.

Step 2, i'm filtering the list of all app registrations with delegated permissions(permission type equal Scope) to a variable `$perms`.

Step3, a graph api request to grab all service principals in azure then add to a ps object called `$sp_data`

Step 4, I'm looping `$perms` object(this object holds apps with only delegated permissions) and filter service principal object `$sp_data` that has all available `delegated permissions` to remain with only apps with only delegated permissions and the permission value., then complete by exporting to csv file.

**Issue**

My script only returns values for one app registration with delegated permissions, instead of all apps. I need assistance to make sure the script can export delegated permissions and application permissions associated with its respective app registration.

Below is my entire script so far

```
# Install MSAL.ps module first & register an app in azure
# The application to use here must have application.readall and directory.readall permissions assigned
$connectiondetails = @{
    # Application (client) ID here
 'clientid' = ""

 # Tenant ID here
 'tenantid' = ""

 # Secret id here
 'clientSecret' = "" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

}


$token = Get-MsalToken @connectiondetails
$tokenid_ = $token.AccessToken

# specify where directory to store the csv files here
$delegatedperms = "C:\temp\delegatedpermissions.csv"
$applicationperms = "C:\temp\applicationpermissions.csv"

# Access token from azure ad oauth app
$accessToken = $tokenid_

# Grab all applications without leaving any app behind.
$all_apps = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications"

$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri $all_apps -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $accessToken)}

# $results
$Data = foreach($res in $results.value){

   ForEach($Access in $res.RequiredResourceAccess){
        foreach ($Permission in $Access.ResourceAccess) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                
                AppName        = $res.DisplayName
                Resource       = $Access.ResourceAppId
                Permission     = $Permission.Id
                PermissionType = $Permission.Type
            }
        }    
    }
  
}

# Filtering applications assigned "delegated permissions" only
$perms = $Data | Where PermissionType -eq "Scope"

$sps = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceprincipals"
$sps_res = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri $sps -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("bearer {0}" -f $accessToken)}

$sp_data = ForEach($sp_res in $sps_res.value){
        ForEach($scope_ in $sp_res.oauth2PermissionScopes){

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                # App_displayname = 
                App_Id = $sp_res.appId
                Permission_Id = $scope_.id
                Permission_Value = $scope_.value
            }
        }  
    }

ForEach($perm in $perms){

    $sp_data | Where-Object (App_Id -match $perm.Resource) -and (Permission_Id -match $perm.Permission)

} # Export to csv here | Export-CSV $delegatedperms
```

My main goal is to have a csv report that resembles this one below
[image]

Comment: Can you please check this similar question for exporting the delegated permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847582/how-to-export-delegated-permissions-assigned-to-azure-app-registration-using-azu

Comment: Mehtab, this is also my question which was regarding to azure-AD cmdlets, this current question is using graph API.