# Retrieve complete "API Permissions" of Azure AD Application via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am using a script from another thread to retrieve all AZ applications, permission type, and permission names but wondering if it is possible to add the capability of the script to show API names for each permission on the output...

[image]

Script:

````
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72847582/how-to-export-delegated-permissions-assigned-to-azure-app-registration-using-azu
#Connect-azureAD 

$Apps = Get-AzureADApplication -All $true
$ServicePrincipals = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true

$export_application_permission = "C:\temp\application_perms.csv"
$export_delegated_permission = "C:\temp\delegated_perms.csv"
$export_all_permission = "C:\temp\all_perms.csv"


$PermissionsList = $ServicePrincipals.Oauth2Permissions | Select-Object  Id, Value
$RolesList = $ServicePrincipals.AppRoles | Select-Object Id, Value



$app.RequiredResourceAccess
$Data = Foreach ($App in $Apps) {
    foreach ($Access in $App.RequiredResourceAccess) {
        foreach ($Permission in $Access.ResourceAccess) {

            switch ($Permission.Type) {
                'Scope' {
                    $PermissionName = ($PermissionsList | Where Id -eq $Permission.Id).Value 
                    break
                }
                'Role' {
                    $PermissionName = ($RolesList | Where Id -eq $Permission.Id).Value 
                    break
                }
            }

            if (!$PermissionName) { $PermissionName = $Permission.Id }
            
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Application Display Name' = $App.DisplayName
                'Permission Type'          = $Permission.Type
                'Permission Value'         = $PermissionName
            }
        }
    }
}

$Data | Where-Object 'Permission Type' -eq Role | Export-Csv -Path $export_application_permission -NoTypeInformation
$Data | Where-Object 'Permission Type' -eq Scope | Export-Csv -Path $export_delegated_permission -NoTypeInformation
$Data | Export-Csv -Path $export_all_permission -NoTypeInformation```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To retrieve the API names for all the permissions, modify the PowerShell script like below:**

```
Connect-AzureAD

$Apps = Get-AzureADApplication -All $true
$ServicePrincipals = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true

$export_application_permission = "C:\application_perms.csv"
$export_delegated_permission = "C:\delegated_perms.csv"
$export_all_permission = "C:\all_perms.csv"

$PermissionsList = $ServicePrincipals.Oauth2Permissions | Select-Object Id, Value
$RolesList = $ServicePrincipals.AppRoles | Select-Object Id, Value

$Data = Foreach ($App in $Apps) {
    foreach ($Access in $App.RequiredResourceAccess) {
        $ApiName = ($ServicePrincipals | Where-Object { $_.AppId -eq $Access.ResourceAppId }).DisplayName
        foreach ($Permission in $Access.ResourceAccess) {

            switch ($Permission.Type) {
                'Scope' {
                    $PermissionName = ($PermissionsList | Where Id -eq $Permission.Id).Value 
                    break
                }
                'Role' {
                    $PermissionName = ($RolesList | Where Id -eq $Permission.Id).Value 
                    break
                }
            }

            if (!$PermissionName) { $PermissionName = $Permission.Id }
            
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Application Display Name' = $App.DisplayName
                'API Name'                 = $ApiName
                'Permission Type'          = $Permission.Type
                'Permission Value'         = $PermissionName
                
            }
        }
    }
}

$Data | Where-Object 'Permission Type' -eq Role | Export-Csv -Path $export_application_permission -NoTypeInformation
$Data | Where-Object 'Permission Type' -eq Scope | Export-Csv -Path $export_delegated_permission -NoTypeInformation
$Data | Export-Csv -Path $export_all_permission -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Now, when I checked **`all_perms.csv`** file, **I am able to get the API names for each permission** successfully:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the speedy rescue and this is perfect!